# PHP mysql refresh select data

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Some code starts with selecting data then check if row numbers are 0 to insert then continue the normal process. The problem is that the normal process is depending on the `select` statement which does not exist because it was stored before the `insert`. How can I refresh data request inside PHP without ajax or anything related to html? Here's an example to explain:

```
$user = $_GET['user']; // not stored user
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE username = ".$user);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($select);
$rownum = mysql_num_rows($select);
if(!$rownum){
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (username, something) VALUES ('$user', 1)");
}

/* Here comes the problem */
if($row['something'] == 0){
   die("Not found !"); // THIS if returns true since it was not found at first place before inserting 
                      // i want it to refresh the $select data so it could be read as 1

}
```

How I solved it so far is by repeatedly using the `$select` and `$row` code below the `insert` statement

```
if(!$rownum){
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (username, something) VALUES ('$user', 1)");
}
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE username = ".$user);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($select);
   [..]
```

I want a simpler way to do this

Comment: you can create a function `GetData()` and move `select` in that and call that function. You need to run `select` query to get data after `insert`.

Comment: @rs. yeah i know, but i'm looking for the most simple way to do it

Comment: The sample code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), which is a very serious [security risk](http://bobby-tables.com/). To fix this hole, switch from the outdated mysql extension to [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) and use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/PDO.prepared-statements), passing values as parameters to the statement rather than interpolating them directly into the string. If you need a PDO tutorial, try ["Writing MySQL Scripts with PHP and PDO"](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html). The site you save may just be your own.

Comment: @outis i know, its just an example to explain my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know whats in the newly created record, you could just create a new array $row=array('username'->'bob', ...);

BUT if you have default values in the table, or add other things later, you going to have to do a second select.

```
$user=urldecode($_GET['user']);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."'");
if(!$result) die("SQL ERROR");

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($select);
}
else
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (username, something) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."', 1)");

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."'");
    if(!$result) die("SQL ERROR");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0) die("MAJOR ERRORS IN SQL");

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
```

I prefer to use $result as this is the result of you running the query.

Comment: rolled back to mysql_query as this was the system currently used by the OP